# add fields with form events in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I try add fields with form events in symfony but fields is add automatically when refresh page ...  scenario is when I fill input email fields body is display ...

code PostType:

```
<?php

    namespace AppBundle\Form;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

    class PostType extends AbstractType
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add('titl')->add('email')->add('phone');
            $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event){
                $post = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();
                   if(!empty($post->getEmail))
                   {
                     $form->add('body');
                   }
                                
                });
            $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class);
        }/**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Post'
            ));
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getBlockPrefix()
        {
            return 'appbundle_post';
        }


    }
```

Comment: This can be done only through Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it says in comment you have to use Javascript to do this, for example make an ajax request to submit the form and to apply, always in javascript, the HTML response.

There is a great video tutorial for this (in french) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0Z-D3MSjA0&t=1504s

Comment: this page https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html could help!